# Sencha Extjs CMD - including custom css

Tags: extjs, cmd, extjs4.1

I used 'sencha generate app' to create my Extjs mvc structure.  I can't figure out where to add my custom css so that it is used in the build.   In Touch, I would put it in app.json.  I've looked in .sencha but can't find any obvious place.   I also want it to work with my index.html while testing.  Do I just put it in my index.html?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>AM</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/default/app.css">

<!-- Like this ?  -->

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/MyApp.css">
<!-- <x-compile> -->
    <!-- <x-bootstrap> -->
        <script src="ext/ext-dev.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
    <!-- </x-bootstrap> -->
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
<!-- </x-compile> -->
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: That's where I put my custom CSS, in the index file.

Comment: Thanks, can't get my darn app to package properly so can't test right now.  Will try to get working.

Answer (score 1):

In the `<HEAD>` section is where you will put your [CSS Style Sheets](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/styles.html) and SCRIPT tags in general.

It is recommended to put your `<SCRIPT>` tags at the bottom of the page (before `</body>`) because the page don't load the rest of the page until the script have finished loading.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>AM</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/default/app.css">

<!-- Like this !  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/MyApp.css">
</head>
<body>

  <script src="ext/ext-dev.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="app/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And what about the production build?

Comment: Same rules apply only you should use the production JS files.

Comment: This is not a 'desirable' way of doing things. Use cmd to generate app, then add external resources to index.htm as shown in [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/command_app) and then use cmd again to build production/testing

Comment: Also i suggest that you take a look at extjs [theming](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/theming). Using custom theme as a package in your app you can easily apply presentation to your app and still make it more extensible and clean.